# How can I run batch processes using nohup?

Tags: ubuntu

I have 5 PHP files that need to be executed simultaneously in the background whenever the server restarts. Each file should be executed at least 4 times.

Currently, I manually paste the entire script into the terminal and press ENTER.

Is this the correct method, or is there a better way to achieve this?

```
nohup php /var/myapp/send-mail.php > /var/log/myapp-log/mail.1.log &
nohup php /var/myapp/send-mail.php > /var/log/myapp-log/mail.2.log &
nohup php /var/myapp/send-mail.php > /var/log/myapp-log/mail.3.log &
nohup php /var/myapp/send-mail.php > /var/log/myapp-log/mail.4.log &
...
...
nohup php /var/myapp/send-push.php > /var/log/myapp-log/push.1.log &
nohup php /var/myapp/send-push.php > /var/log/myapp-log/push.2.log &
nohup php /var/myapp/send-push.php > /var/log/myapp-log/push.3.log &
nohup php /var/myapp/send-push.php > /var/log/myapp-log/push.4.log &
```

However, when running this way, it starts to return several messages as below:

```
/push.4.log &ignoring input and redirecting stderr to stdout
nohup: ignoring input and redirecting stderr to stdout
nohup: ignoring input and redirecting stderr to stdout
nohup: ignoring input and redirecting stderr to stdout




[1]   Exit 255                nohup php /var/myapp/another-script.php > /var/log/myapp-log/listener.1.log
[6]   Exit 255                nohup php /var/myapp/send-mail.php > /var/log/myapp-log/mail.1.log
[7]   Exit 255                nohup php /var/myapp/another-script.php > /var/log/myapp-log/listener.2.log
[12]   Exit 255                nohup php /var/myapp/send-mail.php > /var/log/myapp-log/mail.2.log
[13]   Exit 255                nohup php /var/myapp/another-script.php > /var/log/myapp-log/listener.3.log
[18]   Exit 255                nohup php /var/myapp/send-mail.php > /var/log/myapp-log/mail.3.log
[19]   Exit 255                nohup php /var/myapp/another-script.php > /var/log/myapp-log/listener.4.log
```

How can I correctly run these batch scripts?

Answer (score 0):

Try redirecting stderr to stdout in the above - so at the end of each line you'd add `a 2>&1`
e.g.:

`nohup php /var/myapp/send-push.php > /var/log/myapp-log/push.1.log 2>&1`

That should fix it - however I'd recommend looking at starting these automatically after a reboot - take a look at systemd (or the appropriate service mgr for your OS)

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

I saw that some OS support crontab with @reboot, but I couldn't get it to work on it.

Comment: The script runs fine until one part, after that it seems to get stuck and can't proceed to other scripts.

I also tried putting it inside a .sh file, but that doesn't work either.